# Weird URLs in Fiddler

Tags: web-browser

I was browsing the web and suddenly I started seeing "Waiting for available sockets" error in Chrome with the page showing "Network Unavailable".

I thought that was weird so I opened up Fiddler and saw these strange URLs. Is this something someone has already seen?

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Chrome sends requests to a handful of randomly-generated domain names to detect things like ISPs that return search pages rather than NXDOMAIN, hotspot paywalls (that do much the same) and similar behavior.  The theory is that the 3 random hostnames are unlikely to actually be valid hostnames, and if you get responses to them, something in the middle of your connection is behaving differently than expected.  There's a bug related to this behavior here: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=47262