# Google Chrome Unknown Connections In Proxifire

Tags: virus, chrome

I always using Proxifire in my windows 7 os machine.
This app can show all network traffic through the proxy.
Here is image of my proxifire :

[image: Google Chrome Virus]

Google chrome is close.
So what are those random names connections for google chrome?
Is this a virus?
How can i remove them?
I have malwarebytes + eset internet security latest version(v13.1.21.0 x64) + updated in my windows os.

Comment: This is a known behavior of Chrome. See [Weird URLs in Fiddler](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/60688/weird-urls-in-fiddler). Not malicous.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. So is this a virus or not? because my google chrome is close & send these random connections. How can i prevent them?

Comment: Always there are 6 UnKnown Connections.

Comment: @SilverLight: *"So is this a virus or not?"* - What part of "Not malicious" is unclear? If this is really Chrome (no matter if a window is shown or not) then this is a known behavior and not malicious. Of course, this could be some other process claiming to be chrome.exe in which case it is unknown. But since this is a known behavior with Chrome it likely is Chrome and is behaving normal.

Comment: @Steffen Ullrich you are right - thanks man - I hate windows 10 because i had many problems with this os.